# copy files from folder and then delete some files with an exception

Tags: powershell, shell, get-childitem

I have folder called `Logfolder` in C.

```
C:\LogFolder
```

it has multiple logs with name as follows

```
errorLogs.log
errorLogs.log.1
errorLogs.log.2
errorLogs.log.3

Transmitlogs.log
Transmitlogs.log.1
Transmitlogs.log.2
Transmitlogs.log.3
Transmitlogs.log.4
Transmitlogs.log.5

Receivelogs.log
Receivelogs.log.1
Receivelogs.log.2
Receivelogs.log.3
Receivelogs.log.4

Dataexchange.log
Dataexchange.log.1
```

and many other with the different name but with same extension like .log, .log.1 and so on.

I am interested in only above mention logs.

my goal is to copy this logs starting from `log.1` upto `log.10 or 20` all which exist and than
delete the original file with an exception `.log and .log.1`.

I have achieved following until now.

```
$logLocation = "C:LogFolder"
$tempLocation = "C:\Temp\Logs\"

$LogfileName = "errorLogs.log.", "Transmitlogs.log.","Receivelogs.log.","Dataexchange.log."
foreach ($element in $LogfileName) 
{
$NewLogFileName = -join($element,"*")
Copy-Item -Path "$logLocation\$NewLogFileName" -Destination $tempLocation
}
```

I am able to copy all logs starting from .log.1 and all other which exist.

my problem is how can i delete those logs from original folder without deleting .log and .log.1

I have tried the following but not working.

```
foreach ($element in $LogfileName) 
{
$deleteLogFileName = -join($element,"*")
Remove-Item –path "$logLocation\$deleteLogFileName" -exclude *.log, *.log.1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by selectively **copy** only file `*.log.1` to the destination folder and **move** the others. That would save you removing files from the source location afterwards.

The thing that matters here most is to get a list of files that

- have a numeric extension
- have a basename like 'errorLogs.log', 'Transmitlogs.log', 'Receivelogs.log' or 'Dataexchange.log'

Try

```
$logLocation  = "C:\LogFolder"
$tempLocation = "C:\Temp\Logs"

# if the destination folder does not exist yet, creatre it first
if (!(Test-Path -Path $tempLocation -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $tempLocation -ItemType Directory
}

# get an array of objects of the files where the extension ends in a numeric value
# and where the basename is either 'errorLogs.log', 'Transmitlogs.log', 'Receivelogs.log'
# or 'Dataexchange.log'.
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $logLocation -Filter '*.log*' -File | 
         Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^(errorLogs|Transmitlogs|Receivelogs|Dataexchange)\.log\.\d+$' } | 
         Select-Object FullName, @{Name = 'Number'; Expression = {[int]($_.Name.Split(".")[-1])}}

foreach ($file in $files ) {
    if ($file.Number -eq 1) {
        # this file should be copied
        Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $tempLocation -Force
    }
    else {
        # the others are to be moved
        Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $tempLocation -Force
    }
}
```